# Try::Tinyモジュールの実装方法

Tags: perl

perlで例外処理をするモジュールとしてTry::Tinyがあります。

使うときは以下のように定義しますが、これが文法的にどうやって実装されているか確かめたくてモジュールを読んでみましたが、分かりませんでした。

Javaと同じような文法ですが、perlにはtry構文は用意されていません。
Try::Tinyがどうやってこの文法を実装しているの知りたいです。

> perldoc Try::Tiny

```
         try {
           die_sometimes();
         } catch {
           # ...code run in case of error
         } finally {
           if (@_) {
             print "The try block died with: @_\n";
           } else {
             print "The try block ran without error.\n";
           }
         };
```

以下、モジュールを使わず定義だけしてみて、B::Deparseで構文解析して内部でどう処理されているか確認しましたが、解析結果を見てもよく分かりませんでした。

perl -v: 5.16.2
osx: 10.9.5

```
$cat ./h.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

try {
        print "try\n";
} catch {
        print "catch\n";
};

$perl -MO=Deparse ./h.pl 
use warnings;
use strict;
try {
    print "try\n"
} (catch {
    print "catch\n"
} );
./h.pl syntax OK
```

try()の引数にコードブロックとリストを渡しているのかな？と推察していますが、詳しく分かる方がいらっしゃたら教えてください。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

お察しの通りです。（そのため最後に";"が必要になります）
try/catch/finallyは構文に見せかけた単なるサブルーチン名です。

サブルーチンは引数にコードリファレンスを取る事ができるので以下のように呼ぶ事ができます。

```
sub foo {
    my $code_ref = $_[0];
    return $code_ref->();
}

foo(sub { ... });
```

すでに定義されているサブルーチンは括弧を省略できるので次のようにも書けます。

```
foo sub { ... };
```

さらにサブルーチンプロトタイプで第一引数の基本型を指定しておけば、fooに続く部分がブロックでもハッシュリファレンスでもなく、コードリファレンスであることをperlコンパイラに明示できるので、"sub"を省略できます。

```
sub foo (&) {
    my $code_ref = $_[0];
    return $code_ref->();
}

foo { ... };
```

プロトタイプでコードリファレンスを指定する場合、第一引数にしか適用できないため同じようなプロトタイプを使ったサブルーチンを入れ子にします。

```
sub foo (&;@) {
    my ($code_ref, @rest) = @_;
    return $code_ref->(@rest);
}

sub bar (&) {
    my $code_ref = $_[0];
    return $code_ref->();
}

foo { ... } bar { ... };
```

`bar`がまず処理され、その結果が`foo`の引数`@rest`になります。

Comment: プロトタイプの仕様がイマイチよく分かんなくて。perldoc.jp読んでたらズバリの解説がありました。
[perldoc perlsub](http://perldoc.jp/docs/perl/5.20.1/perlsub.pod#Prototypes)
ただ、foo { ... }, bar { ...}て、間にカンマが不要になるのがまだよく分かんないです。

Comment: 訳文だけ見るとわかりづらいかもしれませんが、実はperlsubに記述はあるんです。`第一引数として渡された場合、& は sub キーワードや連続したカンマを 要求しないような無名サブルーチンを要求します。`　おそらく当時からgrepやmap、sortに似た関数を自前で用意したいという要望があったんではないでしょうか。

Comment: >おそらく当時からgrepやmap、sortに似た関数を自前で用意したいという要望があったんではないでしょうか。
そうですね。以下のようにgrepとmapで組み合わせできますね。
`grep { ... } map { ... } @ary;`
それと同じ原理でしたか。

Comment: grepやmapなどの組み込み関数とは似て非なるものと捉えておいた方がいいかもしれません。例えば特殊変数はグローバルなのでTry::Tinyでいうところのtryの中と外では@_の値が異なります。

Answer (score 1):

Try/Tiny.pmのsub try (&;@) {...}を直接読むしかないかと思います。
http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DOY/Try-Tiny-0.22/lib/Try/Tiny.pm

evalでチェックして、catchしたら$catch->($error)を返してるような感じですね。
あと、モジュールの中身まで見ていきたい場合はperl -dで実行してみましょう。
奥深くまで追いかけることができます。

Comment: デバッガでやってみるとsub catchから実行されてるんですね。てっきり sub tryからと思ってました。もうちょっとデバッガで調べてみます。ありがとうございました。